# How can I use the current Site as the default in a Django form using the Sites Framework?

Tags: django, django-sites

I'm using the Sites Framework and want to save the current site as the default `site` value for one of my models.

Model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(
        Site, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        default=Site.objects.get_current())  # THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO DO (DOESN'T WORK)
    ...other fields...
```

Is there a way to automatically save the current `Site` object as the `site` attribute of `MyModel` anytime I save a `MyModel` instance? Or would I need to do this manually by overriding either the form's or the model's `save` method, (or similar override)?

Comment: What you mean doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the default site.

**models.py**

```
def get_current_site():
    return Site.objects.get_current().id


class MyModel(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(
        Site,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        default=get_current_site)
```

This will only work if you have created a site in your database and also set the `SITE_ID` in `settings.py`